# I can read from local file in py spark but i can't write data frame in local file

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

```
df.write.csv("sdf")
```

> " 21/07/24 15:27:23 ERROR FileFormatWriter:
> Aborting job a9914f88-3ab9-480a-984f-33d0e598c0fc.
> java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:
> org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access0(Ljava/lang/String;I)Z
> at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access0(Native Method)
> at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access(NativeIO.java:645)
> at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.canRead(FileUtil.java:1230)
> at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.list(FileUtil.java:1435)
> at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.listStatus(RawLocalFileSystem.java:493)
> at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.listStatus(FileSystem.java:1868)
> at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.listStatus(FileSystem.java:1910)
> at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.listStatus(ChecksumFileSystem.java:678)
> at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.listStatus(FileSystem.java:1868)
> at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.listStatus(FileSystem.java:1910)
> at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter.getAllCommittedTaskPaths(FileOutputCommitter.java:332)
> at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter.commitJobInternal(FileOutputCommitter.java:402)
> at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter.commitJob(FileOutputCommitter.java:375)
> at org.apache.spark.internal.io.HadoopMapReduceCommitProtocol.commitJob(HadoopMapReduceCommitProtocol.scala:182)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.write(FileFormatWriter.scala:220)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.run(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.scala:188)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:108)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:106)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.doExecute(commands.scala:131)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$execute$1(SparkPlan.scala:180)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$executeQuery$1(SparkPlan.scala:218)
> at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:215)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:176)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:132)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:131)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.$anonfun$runCommand$1(DataFrameWriter.scala:989)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$5(SQLExecution.scala:103)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:163)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1(SQLExecution.scala:90)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:775)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:64)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.runCommand(DataFrameWriter.scala:989)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveToV1Source(DataFrameWriter.scala:438)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveInternal(DataFrameWriter.scala:415)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:293)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.csv(DataFrameWriter.scala:979)
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
> at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
> at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
> at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
> at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
> at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
> at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
> at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in    File
> "C:\spark\python\pyspark\sql\readwriter.py", line 1372, in csv
> self._jwrite.csv(path)   File "C:\spark\python\lib\py4j-0.10.9-src.zip\py4j\java_gateway.py", line
> 1305, in **call**   File "C:\spark\python\pyspark\sql\utils.py", line
> 111, in deco
> return f(*a, **kw)   File "C:\spark\python\lib\py4j-0.10.9-src.zip\py4j\protocol.py", line 328,
> in get_return_value py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred
> while calling o40.csv. : org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted.
> at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.write(FileFormatWriter.scala:231)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.run(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.scala:188)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:108)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:106)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.doExecute(commands.scala:131)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$execute$1(SparkPlan.scala:180)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$executeQuery$1(SparkPlan.scala:218)
> at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:215)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:176)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:132)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:131)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.$anonfun$runCommand$1(DataFrameWriter.scala:989)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$5(SQLExecution.scala:103)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:163)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1(SQLExecution.scala:90)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:775)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:64)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.runCommand(DataFrameWriter.scala:989)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveToV1Source(DataFrameWriter.scala:438)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveInternal(DataFrameWriter.scala:415)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:293)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.csv(DataFrameWriter.scala:979)
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
> at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
> at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
> at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
> at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
> at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
> at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
> at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:
> org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access0(Ljava/lang/String;I)Z
> at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access0(Native Method)
> at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access(NativeIO.java:645)
> at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.canRead(FileUtil.java:1230)
> at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.list(FileUtil.java:1435)
> at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.listStatus(RawLocalFileSystem.java:493)
> at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.listStatus(FileSystem.java:1868)
> at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.listStatus(FileSystem.java:1910)
> at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.listStatus(ChecksumFileSystem.java:678)
> at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.listStatus(FileSystem.java:1868)
> at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.listStatus(FileSystem.java:1910)
> at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter.getAllCommittedTaskPaths(FileOutputCommitter.java:332)
> at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter.commitJobInternal(FileOutputCommitter.java:402)
> at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter.commitJob(FileOutputCommitter.java:375)
> at org.apache.spark.internal.io.HadoopMapReduceCommitProtocol.commitJob(HadoopMapReduceCommitProtocol.scala:182)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.write(FileFormatWriter.scala:220)

Comment: set environment variable HADOOP_HOME then try again

Comment: I had previously set HADOOP_HOME to the C:\winutils path which contained the winutils.exe file.

Answer (score 4):

Apart from getting winutils.exe and setting the hadoop_home.
Please check if you have hadoop.dll binary in your bin or not.
If not there then download it from the github repo.

https://github.com/cdarlint/winutils/blob/master/hadoop-3.2.1/bin/hadoop.dll

It worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

For `PySpark 3.3.1`, `Win10`, `Java 18`.

- Download `bin` folder (from here https://github.com/cdarlint/winutils or here https://github.com/steveloughran/winutils ) with `winutils.exe` and `hadoop.dll` inside it (my version is `3.0.0` or any other greater then `3.0.0`), put the folder into `C:\hadoop`
- Go to `System variables` and create `HADOOP_HOME` and  set to `C\hadoop`.
- Then add it to `path` under `System vars` like that `%HADOOP_HOME%\bin` .

If any issues occur during writing the file json or parquet etc. Just try putting the `hadoop.dll` file into `System32` folder. That's it.

Comment: only thing that worked for me was to put the dll into system32, cheers.

Comment: For me also putting hadoop.dll file into System32 folder worked