# pySpark Unable to save parquet files UnsatisfiedLinkError

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, pyspark

I cannot save my dataframe to local storage.
this mysterious stack trace seems to be linked to some `java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError`. Has anyone seen this type of error?

```
# Define a list of tuples containing data
data = [("Alice", 25), ("Bob", 30), ("Charlie", 28)]

# Define the schema for the DataFrame
columns = ["name", "age"]

# Create a DataFrame using the provided data and schema
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, columns)

# Show the DataFrame
df.show()

# Save the DataFrame as a Parquet file
df.write.parquet(r"C:\GP\music-listening-behaviour\data\02_intermediate\test.parquet")
```

This is the error:

```
>>> ts_formatted.write.csv(r"data/02_intermediate/ts_formatted.csv")
23/08/29 22:05:39 ERROR FileFormatWriter: Aborting job a18f114f-601d-48f8-8dd0-65c1c705f524.
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: 'boolean org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access0(java.lang.String, int)'
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access0(Native Method)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access(NativeIO.java:793)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.canRead(FileUtil.java:1249)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.list(FileUtil.java:1454)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.listStatus(RawLocalFileSystem.java:601)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.listStatus(FileSystem.java:1972)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.listStatus(FileSystem.java:2014)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.listStatus(ChecksumFileSystem.java:761)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.listStatus(FileSystem.java:1972)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.listStatus(FileSystem.java:2014)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter.getAllCommittedTaskPaths(FileOutputCommitter.java:334)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter.commitJobInternal(FileOutputCommitter.java:404)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter.commitJob(FileOutputCommitter.java:377)
        at org.apache.spark.internal.io.HadoopMapReduceCommitProtocol.commitJob(HadoopMapReduceCommitProtocol.scala:192)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.$anonfun$writeAndCommit$3(FileFormatWriter.scala:275)
        at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.timeTakenMs(Utils.scala:640)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.writeAndCommit(FileFormatWriter.scala:275)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.executeWrite(FileFormatWriter.scala:304)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.write(FileFormatWriter.scala:190)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.run(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.scala:190)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:113)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:111)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.executeCollect(commands.scala:125)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.adaptive.AdaptiveSparkPlanExec.$anonfun$executeCollect$1(AdaptiveSparkPlanExec.scala:354)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.adaptive.AdaptiveSparkPlanExec.withFinalPlanUpdate(AdaptiveSparkPlanExec.scala:382)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.adaptive.AdaptiveSparkPlanExec.executeCollect(AdaptiveSparkPlanExec.scala:354)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$$anonfun$eagerlyExecuteCommands$1.$anonfun$applyOrElse$1(QueryExecution.scala:98)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$6(SQLExecution.scala:118)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:195)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1(SQLExecution.scala:103)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:827)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:65)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$$anonfun$eagerlyExecuteCommands$1.applyOrElse(QueryExecution.scala:98)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$$anonfun$eagerlyExecuteCommands$1.applyOrElse(QueryExecution.scala:94)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$transformDownWithPruning$1(TreeNode.scala:512)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.CurrentOrigin$.withOrigin(TreeNode.scala:104)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDownWithPruning(TreeNode.scala:512)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$plans$logical$AnalysisHelper$$super$transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:31)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.transformDownWithPruning(AnalysisHelper.scala:267)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.transformDownWithPruning$(AnalysisHelper.scala:263)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:31)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:31)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDown(TreeNode.scala:488)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.eagerlyExecuteCommands(QueryExecution.scala:94)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.commandExecuted$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:81)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.commandExecuted(QueryExecution.scala:79)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.assertCommandExecuted(QueryExecution.scala:133)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.runCommand(DataFrameWriter.scala:856)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveToV1Source(DataFrameWriter.scala:387)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveInternal(DataFrameWriter.scala:360)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:239)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.csv(DataFrameWriter.scala:847)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:75)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:52)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578)
        at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
        at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:374)
        at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
        at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
        at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
        at py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182)
        at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1623)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\site-packages\pyspark\sql\readwriter.py", line 1799, in csv
    self._jwrite.csv(path)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\site-packages\py4j\java_gateway.py", line 1322, in __call__
    return_value = get_return_value(
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\site-packages\pyspark\errors\exceptions\captured.py", line 169, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\site-packages\py4j\protocol.py", line 326, in get_return_value
    raise Py4JJavaError(
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o228.csv.
: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: 'boolean org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access0(java.lang.String, int)'
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access0(Native Method)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access(NativeIO.java:793)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.canRead(FileUtil.java:1249)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.list(FileUtil.java:1454)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.listStatus(RawLocalFileSystem.java:601)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.listStatus(FileSystem.java:1972)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.listStatus(FileSystem.java:2014)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.listStatus(ChecksumFileSystem.java:761)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.listStatus(FileSystem.java:1972)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.listStatus(FileSystem.java:2014)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter.getAllCommittedTaskPaths(FileOutputCommitter.java:334)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter.commitJobInternal(FileOutputCommitter.java:404)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter.commitJob(FileOutputCommitter.java:377)
        at org.apache.spark.internal.io.HadoopMapReduceCommitProtocol.commitJob(HadoopMapReduceCommitProtocol.scala:192)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.$anonfun$writeAndCommit$3(FileFormatWriter.scala:275)
        at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.timeTakenMs(Utils.scala:640)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.writeAndCommit(FileFormatWriter.scala:275)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.executeWrite(FileFormatWriter.scala:304)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.write(FileFormatWriter.scala:190)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.run(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.scala:190)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:113)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:111)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.executeCollect(commands.scala:125)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.adaptive.AdaptiveSparkPlanExec.$anonfun$executeCollect$1(AdaptiveSparkPlanExec.scala:354)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.adaptive.AdaptiveSparkPlanExec.withFinalPlanUpdate(AdaptiveSparkPlanExec.scala:382)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.adaptive.AdaptiveSparkPlanExec.executeCollect(AdaptiveSparkPlanExec.scala:354)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$$anonfun$eagerlyExecuteCommands$1.$anonfun$applyOrElse$1(QueryExecution.scala:98)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$6(SQLExecution.scala:118)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:195)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1(SQLExecution.scala:103)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:827)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:65)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$$anonfun$eagerlyExecuteCommands$1.applyOrElse(QueryExecution.scala:98)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$$anonfun$eagerlyExecuteCommands$1.applyOrElse(QueryExecution.scala:94)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$transformDownWithPruning$1(TreeNode.scala:512)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.CurrentOrigin$.withOrigin(TreeNode.scala:104)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDownWithPruning(TreeNode.scala:512)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$plans$logical$AnalysisHelper$$super$transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:31)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.transformDownWithPruning(AnalysisHelper.scala:267)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.transformDownWithPruning$(AnalysisHelper.scala:263)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:31)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:31)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDown(TreeNode.scala:488)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.eagerlyExecuteCommands(QueryExecution.scala:94)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.commandExecuted$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:81)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.commandExecuted(QueryExecution.scala:79)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.assertCommandExecuted(QueryExecution.scala:133)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.runCommand(DataFrameWriter.scala:856)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveToV1Source(DataFrameWriter.scala:387)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveInternal(DataFrameWriter.scala:360)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:239)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.csv(DataFrameWriter.scala:847)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:75)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:52)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578)
        at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
        at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:374)
        at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
        at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
        at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
        at py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182)
        at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1623)
```

Answer (score 0):

putting the hadoop.dll in system32 is the only thing that worked for me:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/74482843/5224236

Comment: Yes this happens when you dont set winutils and hadoop, and env. variables issues. I think this was a necessary step when you are running spark on local mode.